# What does Stack Overflow do with similar questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange, duplicate-questions

I don't know if this could be combined to include a recommendation as well as 2 questions, but I noticed that quite a few questions on SO have duplicates.

1. I would like to know whether these duplicates remain open forever, or are they eventually removed over time?
2. Also, (the recommendation - kind of - part) are similar questions that are marked as duplicates used for machine learning to train the Lucene search to optimize better and decrease the volume of duplicate questions?

Comment: Oh, the irony...